# Symfony 4 Match method like tinder

Tags: php, symfony, routes, match, symfony4

I work on a website for my last school project, it's a website where (as a normal user) you can match with a coach and once you two have matched together, you can share a page where the coach can update your daily workout routine.

I'm stucked at the matching method, my entity `User` has a propriety `idCoach` which is an array that can contains other `Users`. The idea is  when you are on the coach's profile page, and you press on the match button, it adds the coach on your idCoach propriety.
This is my propriery from my User entity:

```php
/**
 * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="App\Entity\User", mappedBy="idSportif")
 */
private $idCoach;
```

this is what i tried on the controller :

```php
/**     
 * @Route("/user/match/{id}", name="match")
 */
public function matchCoach(ObjectManager $om, User $user) {
    $currentUser = $this->getUser();
    $currentUser->addIdCoach($user);
    $om->persist($currentUser);
    $om->flush();

    return $this->render('profile/index.html.twig', [
        'user' => $currentUser,
    ]); 

}
```

but it gives me an error message :

> Call to a member function addIdCoach() on null.

Comment: Please give us the code you're working with so we can help you.

Comment: Wherever you try to call `$someVariable->addIdCoach()`, you will find that `$someVariable` is null or hasn't even been defined

Comment: I have added the code, and you're right my actual variable is currently null but i dont know why

Answer (score 1):

so getUser() returns null, that's why you get the error.

Does your Controller extend AbstractController and getUser() should therefore return the currently logged in user? In this case, it seems like you are not logged in. I would check the security configuration to make sure only logged in users can access this url.

Further comments:

- Your naming is a little confusing, what is an "idCoach"? If this property holds the associated coaches, I would name it "coaches".
- Your method changes data, so it should only be called via POST, not GET.